# Search by poster's reputation points in the search bar?

Tags: support, search

Is there a way to search via the poster's reputation points in the search bar?

In my experience so far, a lot of [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) questions seem to be asked by people with low reputation (e.g. one point). From experience, a lot of these low-rep questions tend to be malformed or have pieces missing.

Naturally, people that have been around here longer tend to post better questions, making contributing much easier. My problem at the moment is finding these decent posts (they normally tend to be from users with more than 100 reputation points).

Comment: Not in the search bar (you can see the options [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)), but you could use http://data.stackexchange.com

Comment: For example: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/314649/recent-java-questions-from-higher-rep-users

Comment: I agree this would be helpful. For me, it is the exact opposite reason. I want to answer more questions on StackOverflow, but a lot of the questions that are asked exceed my skill level. I do not think I have a lot to offer someone with 15,000 reputation points. However, someone with 150 reputation points my find my answer helpful.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no way to search for the posts based on the users reputation and are you sure you need that for the use case you describe?

You state you want to find or search among the better questions. Due to the voting on posts a more adequate qualifier for *better* is `score` maybe combined with `views`.

> [`[java] score:10 views:100`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjava%5D+score%3A10+views%3A100)

This gives you questions with a score of 10 or more and over 100 views. This is another reason why voting is important. Down voting bad question and up voting the posts with quality content will help you and others to find the good content.

If you do want to use reputation you can use [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) as indicated by [jonrsharpe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294378/search-by-posters-reputation-points-in-the-search-bar#comment193995_294378) and they provided [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/314649)

There is also a user script [Reputation-based filter for search results](https://stackapps.com/questions/7496/reputation-based-filter-for-search-results) from a Normal Human that let you hide search results from low reputation users.

As an alternative you can use the Stack Exchange API:

```js
   
function search(tag, rep) {
  var  url = 'https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/search/advanced?order=desc&sort=activity&accepted=True&closed=False&tagged=' + tag + '&site=stackoverflow',
  xhr;

  xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', url);
  xhr.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var result,
        response,
        li,
        a,
        item,
        i;
   
     if (xhr.status === 200 && 
         xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
       result = document.getElementById('result');
       response = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
       // clear result
       while (result.firstChild) {
          result.removeChild(result.firstChild);
       }
       for(i = 0; i < response.items.length; i++) {
         item = response.items[i];
         if (item.owner && item.owner.reputation > rep) {
           li = document.createElement('li');
           a = document.createElement('a');
           a.href = item.link;
           a.textContent = item.title;
           li.appendChild(a);
           result.appendChild(li);
         }
       }
    }
  });
  xhr.send();
}

(function () {
  document.getElementById('search').addEventListener('click', function() {
    search(document.getElementById('tag').value,
           parseInt(document.getElementById('rep').value,10));
    });
}())
```

```html
<div>
  <div>
    <label for="tag">tag:</label>
    <input id="tag" type="text" value="java" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="rep">rep:</label>
    <input id="rep" type="number" value="100" />
  </div>
  <button id="search">search</button>
</div>
<ul id='result'>
</ul>
```