# Add ability to search by rep

Tags: feature-request

I've already seen this question: [Search by poster's reputation points in the search bar?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294378/search-by-posters-reputation-points-in-the-search-bar) and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching, and it appears this is still not possible.

So here I am, requesting it to be added as a search feature. Can we please add the ability to filter searches by the rep of the asker? Pretty please?

**Justification**: Users with higher rep tend to ask more clear & concise questions and respond to answers appropriately.  In my case I specialize in a few tags that are chock full of one time, 1 rep askers who either never respond or need to be prodded to mark answers as correct. I don't mind dealing with these questions as well but sometimes I'm not in the mood and just want to cut through to get at some higher quality content. The ability to filter for users with a minimum rep, even say "25" would cut out a lot of noise.

Comment: IIRC, this has been declined multiple times in the past since it, "excludes newbies". So if you want to filter them out, you'll need to resort to a custom solution.

Comment: Ok thanks, have there been any requests here on meta?  I did not find any, sorry if it's a dupe.

Comment: https://stackapps.com/questions/4888/filter-se-questions-by-votes-views-and-rep

Comment: apparently everyone hates this idea.

Answer (score 13):

> Users with higher rep tend to ask more clear & concise questions and respond to answers appropriately.

[This is the single greatest myth about the site, so I felt it appropriate to the "The" OP to illustrate this point.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44999822/1079354)

[Just so that this is a two-way street, I'm fairly high-rep and was at the time I wrote that, and still managed to ask this really "poor" question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33533816/1079354)

You are not obligated in any way, shape, form or fashion to answer any questions you don't feel like.  The system isn't meant to make it any easier for you since you're ***really*** not meant to be judging someone based on their reputation whatsoever, but if you see a question you don't feel like answering, **don't answer it.**

Comment: It's not a myth, it's my first-hand experience with the tags I look at.  90 - 95% of the 1 rep askers are questions that get closed.  It's a headache.

Comment: Just to play devil's advocate, one counter example isn't enough to refute a supposed correlation between rep and question quality.

Comment: @Mysticial:  No, it isn't.  But "The" OP has twenty or so examples for one to peruse in quiet hour.  The intention here was simply to demonstrate that reputation ***really*** doesn't matter when it comes to question quality.  For grins I'll even throw a question I did that was poorly received, too.

Comment: @Makoto, the point of this request is not that high rep users don't ask crap questions.  It's that low rep users do.  And that is a verifiable fact.  Many of them just have no idea what the rules of the site are because they haven't been around long enough to learn.  It's not a dis and I'm not going to exclude them, but I've used my eyes as a filter enough times to know this is true.  Sometimes I'm looking for higher quality content and a programmatic filter would just make more efficient use of my time.

Comment: @billynoah:  90-95% of the accounts you interact with have 1 rep because **90-95% of the accounts that are asking have _just_ started.**  Everyone starts with 1 rep.  The vast majority of accounts aren't active here.  There can be no safe correlation between reputation and question-asking ability.

Comment: Sure it doesn't matter. But let's assume there is a strong correlation between rep and question quality. A user acting out of self-interest who is aware of this correlation can save a lot of time by utilizing this information to filter out low rep users. Sure it goes against the spirit of the site. But every user is free to act on their own (within the rules).

Comment: @Mysticial: I don't disagree.  But the platform shouldn't make it any easier or incentivize this kind of behavior, since it's truly provable that it's a false flag.

Comment: @Makoto I actually disagree that it's a false flag (i.e. no correlation). But that's a different topic.

Comment: @Mysticial - I agree and my own questions were much lower quality when I was 1 rep.  There's nothing wrong with that.  I'm not judging anyone for being a newbie, as you said it's where we all start.  I just don't always want to slog through those questions and when you are looking at a tag that has 50 1 rep questions in a row, it starts to feel like a waste of time

Comment: @billynoah:  Just to drive the point home a bit more:  there's about 5,792,750 accounts with exactly 1 rep.  There's about 2,800,172 with *more* than 1 rep.  You're going to run into 1-rep accounts **a heck of a lot more often** than you are someone with more than 1 rep.

Comment: I don't disagree with that statement at all.  I still want my rep filter :-)

Comment: @billynoah:  There's an official API for Stack Exchange, and you likely have a text editor.  Have at.

Comment: users with high rep tend to not ask questions *anymore.* They may have in the past

Comment: @KevinB - my personal use case would be filtering users with rep of 50 or higher.  that would still include newbies, just not newbie newbies

Comment: @KevinB:  Users with high rep may not ask because they either know the answer, or they know the kind of answer they'd get from us (including no answer at all).  It's kind of a problem.

Comment: @billynoah If you do go with a rep filter, I suggest a threshold of 5 rep instead of 50. 5 rep is only one upvote. But from my experience, it's already enough to filter out the vast majority of the garbage out there. Most of the one-time trash users won't get past even that barrier. So 5 rep is enough to bring the signal-to-noise ratio to something a lot more tolerable.

Comment: @Mysticial - sounds reasonable thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @billynoah Yeah, don't bother setting the threshold above 50 or a 100. Beyond that and it's all diminishing returns. (perhaps *that's* what these guys are referring to when they say it's a "false signal") The correlation is really only apparent at the lowest rep levels.

Comment: @Makoto: or, more likely, users with a high rep know *how to find answers*. Did anyone ever cross 10K purely by asking questions?

Comment: @usr2564301 Yes, there are people with more than that rep just from questions.  You don't want to come across their questions, they're terrible.  Some help vampires create a new account every time they have a bad question, and some use the same account.

Comment: @usr2564301:  Did you *miss* the example where I used ["The" OP](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/79811/175248)?

Comment: @Makoto: I didn't click the link, but now I did I wished I had not. It erodes my will to help others down to a nub. Some people are givers, some people are ... *not*. To think this person has moderator-like powers at his fingertips, and may be expecting a 100K Bag Of Swag any time soon 

Comment: How are the 2 questions you linked poor? To me it seems they’re clear, well-written, well-formatted, and high-quality.

Answer (score 9):

*If* as you seem to think, only low-rep users ask poor questions (and *if* low-rep users *only* ask poor questions), those questions get quickly downvoted, so:

One alternative is to search by *votes*. Ex:

```
[python] subprocess score:1 is:question
```

will return the questions belonging to the [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) tag, containing "subprocess", with a score at least of 1 (and it applies to all users, low or high rep, so you see there's no need to filter)

Another good method is to [avoid the site on sunday evenings](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365082/raise-the-limits-on-down-close-votes-at-weekends-and-especially-sundays).

The only drawback is that you can't be the first one seeing the question. You have to wait for others to vote, lowering your chances to answer first.

The greatness of StackOverflow is that anyone can contribute, even starters on the site (which may have outside experience, BTW). I've seen okay questions by low-rep users, and very bad questions by high-rep users who just switched technology from [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) to [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) and which don't have a clue.

Comment: Thanks - I've been using score filter for a while, and though this filter works fine on more active topics, unfortunately it doesn't really work if you are browsing obscure tags with not much activity.  e.g., [opencart]  - most of the questions, even the good ones, lack much voting activity at all.

Comment: yeah, that's the trouble. But if there's not much activity on those tags, there aren't that many questions to filter either.

Answer (score 8):

Fundamentally, we should focus on content, *not* users. This site exists for the benefit of all, not just for high-rep users who have been around for awhile.

A better solution would be for more people to work the review queues so that we could get rid of low-quality content faster.

Also, just as a plug, the Stack Overflow Close Vote Reviewers chat room is always glad for more people to help out with moderating content.

Answer (score -6):

The comments about not helping legitimate new users by filtering them are not thought out.

You can allow only filtering for users with some higher reputation, say 1000.

You can also add probabilistic filtering as well, the lower the user's rep then the less likely you will see a message.

You should also add filtering by the ratio of questions asked to answers accepted.

Really, the problem is there is a 100 to 1 ratio of nonsense posts to meaningful posts. It's not just posts about questions that could be easily researched or are obvious duplicates. It's more about questions that seems like it's just a bunch of bots posting random pseudo questions and the "poster" doesn't care about the answer anyway.